# COUNT MANY FIELDS IN ACCESS

Tags: sql, field

I have a database table like this:

```
 ID   NAMEID      ClASSID    SEX    
---------------------------------
  1       1          1        0
  2       1          1        1
  3       1          1        1
  4       2          2        1
  5       2          2        0
  6       2          2        1
  7       2          2        1
```

Please help me, how to have a result, as follows: (use query in Access)

```
NameID      ClassID    SEX   MALE   FEMALE
--------------------------------------------    
   1          1         3      2       1
   2          2         4      3       1
```

Thanks so much

Comment: It seems like a group by matter but I think you need to describe each field's intention to get an answer.

Answer (score 2):

I assume that you want to group on the `NameId` and `ClassId` fields, and that the `Sex` field in the result is not sex at all, but the number of persons.

Something like this:

```
select
  NameId,
  ClassId,
  count(*) as Sex,
  sum(Sex) as Male,
  count(*) - sum(Sex) as Female
from
  TheTable
group by
  NameId,
  ClassId
```

#### Edit:

For Sex values 1 and 2 you can use a `case` to count them:

```
  sum(case Sex when 1 then 1 else 0 end) as Male,
  sum(case Sex when 2 then 1 else 0 end) as Female
```

Comment: I have a mistake, Field [SEX] with value: 1 ,2 not 0.

Comment: @user3359859: I added an alternative way to count them above.

Comment: I try but its not active

Comment: @user3359859: What do you mean?